# check if expression within list comprehension is empty string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have this list comprehension:

```
[''.join(letter for letter in word if not letter.isdigit()) for word in words]
```

What I am trying to do is for each `word` in the list `words` check if the `word` consists of *numbers*. If the word has numerical characters it will exclude it from the final output.

For example, `remove_numbers(['lion', 'tiger99', 'yes7', '9'])` gives me:

```
['lion', 'tiger', 'yes', '']
```

However, I would like to also exclude empty strings in the final output. So the desired output is:

```
['lion', 'tiger', 'yes']
```

I have tried to add the `if not word` in the list comprehension. Unfortunately this did not work. Anyone can help?

Comment: `[''.join(letter for letter in word if not letter.isdigit()) for word in words if not word.isnumeric()]`

Comment: You can use regular expression for it

```
import re
[ word if not re.search('\d',word) for word in words]

```

Comment: `if not word.isnumeric()` not `if not word`

Comment: If you want to remove numbers you can use this code

`[re.sub('\d', '', word) for word in words if not word.isnumeric()]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if not word` doesn't work in your example because the last *"word"* is not an empty string `''` but it is `'9'`, your *processed output* is the empty string and it is appended to your output array.

@aminrd's suggestion should do it, here we check if the input word is purely numeric, this won't work with decimals though.

**sample code**:

```
words = ['lion', 'tiger300', 'yes7', '9']
print([''.join(letter for letter in word if not letter.isdigit()) for word in words if not word.isnumeric()])

# or using regex
import re
print([re.sub('\d', '', word) for word in words if not word.isnumeric()])
```

**Output**

```
['lion', 'tiger', 'yes']
```

Since you wanted to know how to check the output word is empty in list comprehension

**Code**:

```
words = ['lion', 'tiger300', 'yes7', '9']
print([x for x in [''.join(letter for letter in word if not letter.isdigit()) for word in words] if x])
```

**Output**

```
['lion', 'tiger', 'yes']
```

But this one would be inefficient the first method should be preferred since it creates only one list this creates two and first is more easy to read.

Comment: How can I check the appended output is empty in this list comprehension?

Comment: @jxpython perform list comprehension on the output array

Comment: @jxpython I've edited the answer but first method should be more efficient why go for this?

Comment: Is [re.sub('[0-9]', '', word) for word in words if not word.isnumeric()] better/faster?

Comment: @jxpython I'm not sure which one is faster, but you'll have  to import the extra module for this method. You can also use this regex expression `re.sub('\d', '', word)`